# Fatal Error Call to undefined function SearchApiViewsQuery():placeholder

Tags: views, search

I am using **search api** and **views** module
When I add fields Indexed user **first name** and indexed user **last name**
and then use field **views combine fields filter** and add those two fields I get the **undefined function error**

Basically I want to add a keyword search option to the views which is using index values of a search api
Is there any other option to implement keyword search in drupal

Comment: It looks like a bugreport. Could you tell us why you think it isn't? Module should never throw a fatal error if it's not buggy, everything user can input in it's settings should be covered and handled gracefully.

Comment: i dont know whether its a bug report , I just wanted some advice if I am wrong somewhere out in choosing views combine fields filter

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Realname module on your site? I'd suggest doing it on a copy of the site to test first as it affects quite a lot of things, but if you're doing searches for names it may help, sounds like search api is getting confused trying to join the two fields, so perhaps a different approach may help.

https://www.drupal.org/project/realname

HTH

Steve